# Can we move Dummy from global namespace to my own namespace?

Tags: c#

I want to create a method as a mathematics expression evaluator for the given

- input of math expression in terms of x and y where are both complex numbers,
- input of x which is a complex number,
- input of y which is also a complex number.

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting;
using System;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Dummy
{
    public Complex x;
    public Complex y;
}

namespace Simpler
{
    static class Program
    {

        public static Complex Function(this string e, Complex x, Complex y)
        {
            Script<Complex> s = CSharpScript.Create<Complex>(e, globalsType: typeof(Dummy));

            Complex z = s.RunAsync(new Dummy { x = x, y = y }).Result.ReturnValue;

            return z;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Complex x = new Complex(1, 1); // x = 1 + i
            Complex y = new Complex(0, 1); // y = i

            //string e = "x*y"; // x*y = (1 + i)* i = i + i^2 = i - 1 = -1 + i
            string e = "x/y"; // x/y = (1 + i)/ i = 1/i + 1 = -i + 1 = 1 - i

            string lhs = Regex.Replace(e, "x", x.ToString());
            lhs = Regex.Replace(lhs, "y", y.ToString());

            Console.WriteLine($"{lhs} = {e.Function(x, y)}");


        }
    }
}
```

## Questions

Can we move `Dummy` from global namespace to my own namespace `Simpler`?

Comment: Yes.. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy the class into your namepspace like this:

```
namespace Simpler
{

   public class Dummy
   {
       public Complex x;
       public Complex y;
   }
}
```

I would suggest to put it in another file called Dummy.cs or something similar. After you´ve done that you should have access to this class from your Namespace Simpler.

Comment: globalsType: typeof(Dummy) defines a parameter for the CSharpScript method. The Parameters name is globalsType.You can look this up under [CSharpScript.cs](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting/CSharpScript.cs). In Csharp you basically can set specific parameters for methods with setting them with this notation.